# Code conversion from Laravel-4 to Laravel-5

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm implementing real time chat using [Laravel 4 Real Time Chat](https://xuri.me/2014/09/08/laravel-4-real-time-chat.html). I have problem in converting this code as I have never used Laravel 4.

```
require app_path().'/filters.php';
require app_path().'/events.php';
```

The above link saids to write these two lines in `app/start/global.php`. But in laravel 5 there is no such file. Should I save  events.php in app directory or in app/events.

Is it possible to use this code in laravel-5? or How would I solve the above issue?

Comment: Have you tried adding it to the `bootstrap/autoload.php` file?

Answer (score 1):

I would add it to the boot method of your app service provider
app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php